# Make persistent changed JavaScript in Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it any way to debug any page's JavaScript by saving it, changing it and reload page with that changed JS?

Tried to save changes in Sources in Developer Tools but it works only until page not reloaded.

Also tried to use Workspaces but didn't get sense: if I change any linked file in workspace folder — it causes an error "workspace mapping mismatch".

Comment: The developer tools allow you to edit a local copy. If you want the changes you make to be permanent, you need to edit the source file.

Answer (score 2):

Workspaces is the way to go for you.
You have probably setup them incorrectly though.
The script resource that you load from the network should be served from the same file that you edit in DevTools.

Also disabling cache in DevTools should help against browser caching old script version.

Comment: What I'm doing wrong?

1. http://i.imgur.com/QnzyLwb.png

2. http://i.imgur.com/aA1ECcR.png